# How do I share scope between two directives in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to share the `$scope` between the following two directives:

```
One23SRCApp.directive('directive1',function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.tablename = "table";
        }
    };
});


One23SRCApp.directive('directive2',function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           var tablename = scope.tablename;
        }
    };
})
```

In the HTML, I have:

```
<input type="text" directive2 placeholder="Search Models..."> 

<table directive1>
  <tr>
     <td>column1</td>
     <td>column1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have created the directive named "directive1" with isolated scope, assigning the name "table" to the `scope.tablename` property. I am not able access this scope property in the other directive.

So how can I access the scope of one directive in another?

Comment: How are the directives organized in html?

Comment: @chnadermani i have updated my question, i have apply directive on different element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a `$rootScope.$broadcast` on items that you need to sync across directive.

Or you can pass a object to your directive1 isolated scope, which would act as a communication mechanism. On this object if you change sub property like `tablename`, that would affect in the parent scope.

Something like

```
One23SRCApp.directive('directive1',function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{tableconfig:'='},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.tableconfig.tablename= "table";
        }
    };
});


One23SRCApp.directive('directive2',function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           var tablename = scope.tableconfig.tablename;
        }
    };
})
```

The HTML becomes

```
<table directive1 tableconfig='tableconfig'>
  <tr>
     <td>column1</td>
   <td>column1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Your controller should have this object defined

`$scope.tableconfig={};`

Comment: Using $rootScope is an anti-pattern

Comment: This is a bad practice, your isolated scope is polluted if you only want to share the same scope between directives.

Comment: @Chandermani. I stuck related this issue with very badly.I am new in angular could you see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521905/set-one-showrangeselector-for-two-dygraph thanks

Answer (score 21):

AngularJS supports directive controllers, which are controllers that are shared between multiple directives that require the same controller. This allows you to access and modify `tableConfig` in any directive that requires that controller, without having to declare a separate service or event. For more information, look at "Creating Directives that Communicate" in the [directives documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate).

This is how `ngModel` and `ngForm` work, for example.

Comment: Nice, I had missed that option completely.

Comment: can't find anything on "controller constructor" there anymore. But maybe it is the "Creating Directives that Communicate"-section you are talking about?

Comment: You're right, the documentation was changed, I'm updating the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

My suggestion would be to use a shared resource, e.g. a service. Services are singletons, meaning there is only ever one instance of each service, so you can use them to share data between directives, controllers, scopes and even when changing page through routing.

You would define the resource service like this:

```
app.factory("MyResource",function(){
    return {};
});
```

You could then inject that service into your directives (and controllers if need be) and use it like this.

```
One23SRCApp.directive('directive1', ['MyResource', function(MyResource) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           var resource = MyResource;
           resource.name = 'Foo';
        }
    };
});
One23SRCApp.directive('directive2', ['MyResource', function(MyResource) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           var resource = MyResource;
           console.log(resource.name);
        }
    };
});
```

Directive2 will log 'Foo' since the resource is shared. Although make sure your directives are run in the correct order!

**

You could also do a two way data-binding from each directive into the parent scope (see Chandermani answer for that), but the above is a very useful and powerful way to get data where you need it without having to broadcast or keep track of exactly where things are in the html.

**Edit:**
While the above is very useful when sharing info between controllers and routes, check out stevuu answer. It seems better for directives (although I have not tried it).

Answer (score 4):

The sample of Chandermani is working. However this way you still have to assign the attribute on your directive and its not isolated anymore. This is a pollution on the scope...

My advice is to share your isolated scope by using the controller an passing it this way.
Your house, your code! Think before you code but most of all... ENJOY!

```
One23SRCApp.directive('directive1',function() {
    return {
         restrict: "A",
         scope: true,
         controller : function($scope){
              $scope.tableconfig= {};
              this.config = function (){ 
                   return $scope.tableconfig;
              }
         },
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.tableconfig.tablename= "table";
         }
    }
});


One23SRCApp.directive('directive2',function() {
     return {
           restrict: "A",
           //^ -- Look for the controller on parent elements, not just on the local scope
           //? -- Don't raise an error if the controller isn't found
           require: "^directive1",
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
               var tablename = scope.config().tablename;
           }
    }
});
```

**Usage**

```
<!-- Notice, no need to share a scope as attribute -->
<div directive1>
    <div directive2>
    </div>
</div>
```