# Pass element from link function to controller function inside directive and than to another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink, scope, directive

Is a way to pass an element from link function to controller function inside directive and than to another directive as its element?

I mean I have a directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('parentDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
    element = //some HTML code
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      this.elem = function () {
        $scope.elem = element;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then I have another directive where I want to get the `$scope.elem`.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('childDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    link: function (scop, elmn, attr){

    // HOW TO GET THE $scope.elem here as elmn ?
    elmn = $scope.elem ?

    }
  }
});
```

**Is it possible to pass the `element` into the `$scope.elem` and than to another directive ?**

Edit: thanks guys for help, I also found another way to do this via `factory` [under this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18466405/4713535)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for a way for the child directive to get the element from the parent directive. You can do this using a common technique for directive-to-directive communication, where the child directive gains access to the parent directive's controller:

Parent Dir:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('parentDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
       element = //some HTML code
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
      this.elem = function () {
          return $element;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Child Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('childDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    require: '^parentDir',
    link: function (scop, elmn, attr, parentCtrl){    
         var parentElmn = parentCtrl.elem(); 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for `$element`.  Didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to access the parent controller from the child controller, then the best option would be to use require and inject the parent controller in the link function of the child.

If you only need to access the scope, you could also set scope to false in the child directive. but this is an approach that could  result in some confusion as your code gets more complex.

Below is an example of how you could possibly access the parent directive from the child directive (my preferred approach)

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('parentDir', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div style="background: yellow">This is the parent dir and value is <strong>{{ val }}</strong><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,

      controller: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.val = true;

        this.element = $element;

        this.updateVal = function(newVal) {
          $scope.val = newVal
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('childDir', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^parentDir',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class="append" style="background: red; margin: 15px"><h5>This is the child dir</h5><button ng-click="change()">change parent scope</button></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attr, parentCtrl) {

        //if you want access to the parent element
        var parentElem = parentCtrl.element;

        //if you want to execute a function in the parent directive
        scope.change = function() {
          //note that because of protoypical inheritance, scope.val can be accessed in the child directive
          parentCtrl.updateVal(!scope.val)
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app='app'>

<head>
  <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js'></script>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <parent-dir>

    <child-dir>

    </child-dir>

  </parent-dir>
</body>

</html>
```

hope this helps.