# how to pass data between different directives in angular 1x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Directive 1

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .directive("directive1", directive1);

directive1.$inject = ["$compile"];

function directive1($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "app/views/directive1template.html",
        scope: {
            ui: '=info',
        },
        compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
                },
                post: function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
                    console.log(scope);
                }
            }
        }

    };}}());
```

Directive 2

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .directive("directive2", directive2);

directive2.$inject = ["$compile"];

function directive1($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "app/views/directive2template.html",
        scope: {
            customer: '=info',
        },
        compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
                },
                post: function (scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
                    console.log(scope);
                }
            }
        }

    };}}());
```

Template

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="d3FormRows" class="well">
        <!--custom directive placeholder-->
        <directive2 info="data" index="$index"></directive2>
        <!--custom directive placeholder-->

    </div>
</div>
```

What I am looking for here if there is someway I can access `directive2` `scope` properites/values inside `directive1`?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share scope between two directives in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465851/1575353)

Answer (score 0):

Normally You would use a service for data exchange and then inject that service in both directives.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

For example:

```
angular
.module("app")
.service("MyDataService", function(){
    return {
        var1:'value1'
    }
});
```

then inject this 'MyDataService' service in both directives and this way you can change data in one place and "see" changes in other directive.

Basically '.service' is same as '.factory', the main difference is that one returns same instance (as Singleton), other return new instance for each directive.